# Chronoforms 6: No redirect after submit and show message

Tags: chronoforms

How kann I avoid a redirect after submiting a form and show the success message? Seems to be unusual, cause I haven't found much info about it.

Answer (score 0):

ChronoForms doesn't do anything after the form is submitted unless you add action(s) under the submit tab.

Under Basic actions there is a "Message" action that displays a message.

Under Basic actions there is a "Redirect" action where you can specify a url to redirect to.

It sounds like you may need to delete the Redirect action and add a Message action.

Including a screen capture in your question might help diagnose the problem.